# Blocking whole UI with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am developing a mobile App using Smartface.

In my page NavigationBar and ActionBar are in use.

During a network operation I want to prevent user to perform actions. It is possible to block the UI under navigation & action bars.

How can I prevent user interacting with bars?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent your UI by using a rectangle with adjusting it as a fullSize.

Smartface 5.0.0 version will bring you to enable or disable the functionalities of NavigationBar / ActionBar buttons.